# Rails, f.check_box returns both true and false when checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I my app I have some checkboxes for an array called "level", each one looks like this(just with different values):

```
<%= f.check_box(:level, { :multiple => true, :id => 'level1', :class => 'input_values levels' }, 'All', 'false') %>
```

My problem is that when I check a box, I get both the value and 'false'. If I set the 'false' to nil, I get nothing when I uncheck the box.

If I for example, have the choice between 
- all 
- easy (checked)
- intermediate (checked)
- hard

**I need the "level" array to print out something like this:**

[ 'false', 'easy', 'intermediate', 'false']

Right now it's printing out something like this:

[ 'false', 'false', 'easy', 'false', 'intermediate', 'false']

My ActiveRecord::Base

```
serialize :level, Array
```

My controller

```
def gamesession_params
      params.require(:gamesession).permit(:players, :flares, :aliens, :gamesetup, expansion:[], level:[])    
end
```

Comment: in ruby a 'false' (String) is true..
so it would be better to set it to nil instead of "false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [top comment in the API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box#1001-Sending-array-parameters) points it out correctly, your `'false'` has to be `nil`.

`<%= f.check_box(:level, { :multiple => true, :id => 'level1', :class => 'input_values levels' }, 'All', nil) %>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my problem is that, if it's set to nil then it won't push anything to my array when it's false. And I need it to say false in the array.

Comment: Sadly you didn't post your data models but I have the suspicion that it can be improved. Wether the values in the array are nil or false shouldn't matter to you.